# Consuming ArcGIS Online map service using static IP address for VPN?

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm currently using the URL http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer for my iPad map service.

However, we need to connect to VPN to access the internal network at the same time, and the VPN server blocks the public Internet, and only allows me to setup IP Address based public Internet access.

Is there static IP addresses associated to the above URL that I could specify?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DNS lookup to find out what IP address a DNS points to. No guarantees that its static however.
An example service - http://www.dnswatch.info/

Gives the result: **195.225.189.243** for that URL

Comment: Just a quick Point. ArcGIS online services are provided through a CDN, and the best servers for different users can be different. Just a point to remember.